# matlabで関数 'kroneckerDelta'が未定義といわれる

Tags: matlab

以下のバンドストップフィルタをmatlabでによプログラミングしています．

```
%窓関数法によるFIRフィルタの設計
wp = 0.2*pi; ws = 0.4*pi; %通過域端周波数,素子域端周波数
w1 = 0.2*pi; w2 = 0.4*pi;
w0 = (w1+w2)/2;
trwidth = ws-wp; %遷移帯域幅
N = ceil(6.6*pi/trwidth)+1 %ハミング窓の長さ (タップ長)
win = hamming(N); %ハミング窓
%窓関数によるFIRフィルタの設計 (単位インパルス応答)
wc = (w2-w1)/2; %遮断周波数
n = -(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2; %時刻の範囲
h = (2*kroneckerDelta(n))-(diag(2*cos(n*w0))*transpose((wc/pi)*sinc(n*wc/pi))); %設計された単位インパルス応答
subplot(2,2,1); 
stem(n,h); %単位インパルス応答の図示
axis([-(N-1)/2 (N-1)/2 -0.1 0.3]); grid;
xlabel('Time n'); ylabel('g(n)');%設計されたFIRフィルタの周波数応答
dw = 0.001; %周波数の刻み
w = -20*pi:dw:20*pi; %周波数の範囲
H = freqz(h,1,w);
maxH = max(abs(H)); %周波数応答の最大値
dBH = 20*log10(abs(H)/maxH); %振幅特性の正規化
subplot(2,2,2);
plot(w,dBH); %振幅特性の図示
axis([-4*pi 4*pi -80 5]); grid;
xlabel('Frequency \omega [rad]'); ylabel('|H(e^{j\omega})| [dB]');
Rp = -min(dBH(1:ceil(wp/dw)+1)) %通過域リプルの確認
As = -max(dBH(ceil(ws/dw)+1:length(w))) %阻止域減衰量の確認
```

しかし，以下のようなエラーが出てしまい，バンドストップフィルタの単位インパルス応答の形成に必要な
クロネッカーのデルタ関数が出力できません．（なお，クロネッカーのデルタ関数は，nと同期させて2を出力させたいと存じております．）

```
関数 'kroneckerDelta' (タイプ'double' の入力引数) が未定義です。

エラー: matlab_bandstopFIR (line 11)
h = (kroneckerDelta(n))-(diag(2*cos(n*w0))*transpose((wc/pi)*sinc(n*wc/pi))); %設計された単位インパルス応答
```

つきましては，大変恐縮ですが，どなた様か，ご存知の方がおられましたら，何卒ご教授願えますと，大変ありがたく存じます．
何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます．

Answer (score 1):

まず、kroneckerDelta関数 は Symbolic Math Toolbox に含まれるようなので、
この[ツールボックスのインストール済みを確認](http://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/calling-functions.html#bsn_e9n-6)してください。